# How to show the Accessibility pane in Xcode's attribute inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility, xcode-storyboard

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app) you can configure VoiceOver properties of the UI elements in the Accessibility pane in the attribute inspector.

[image: Accessibility pane]

On the other hand this pane is not visible for me for any UIElements (buttons or labels). I'm using the latest XCode 10.12.1. All I see is an 'Accessibility' checkbox with seemingly no effect.

[image]

How can I configure the Accessibility properties (Label, Hint, Identifier) of the UI elements using the storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Identity inspector instead of Attributes inspector:

[image: Identity Inspector]

Accessibility properties at the middle:

[image: Accessibility]